# how can i configure tinymce to insert spans into list tags

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, html-lists, html

I am using the tinyMCE in wordpress and I would like to alter the numbered list html so that when the editors create the lists using the button in between each li, a span is also added.

### Current

```
<ol>
<li>this</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>current</li>
</ol>
```

### Required

```
<ol>
<li><span class="test">this</span></li>
<li><span class="test">is </span></li>
<li><span class="test">what i want </span></li>
</ol>
```

my preference is to make the span the default when clicking on numlist button, but if it is easy to make a custom button to achieve this that advice would be very welcome too.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible out of the box.

Comment: Thariama, do you know how can I make it possible?

Comment: you would nee to write your own plugin for this functionality - in this case this would take alot of time

Comment: I appreciate its not possible out of the box. Anyone out there got some out of the box thinking on how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone else is interested I did achieve the end out come but not through modifying the tinymce editor as the tinymce custom button route is not one i have time to pursue.

So instead I manipulated the 'content' on its way out of the db and did some simple regex  preg__replace and str_replace work to end up with what i what i needed.

so the content manager now just creates an unordered list and adds numbers themselves at the start.  we then loop through and adds in the span and p tags around the content and number. which then means the content can be styled beautifully! not an ideal solution but it works for now.

example $content = "1.Help me do this"

```
    $content = str_replace("<li>","<li><p>",$content);
    $content = str_replace("</li>","</p></li>",$content);
    $pattern = "/(<p>?)+([0-9]{1,}\.?)/";
    echo preg_replace($pattern,"<span>$2</span> $1",$content);
```